# windows store app listview update

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps

i have a listview that is binded to collection in code-behind.
so, when i add to a collection new item as follows:

```
collection.add(new CollectionItem());
```

ListView is updated, and everything works.
But then i want to sort the collection:

```
collection = new ObservableCollection(collection.orderBy(key));
```

and listview doesn`t updates.
i tried to do that as follows:

```
sCollection = new ObservableCollection(collection.orderBy(key));

foreach(CollectionItem item in sCollection)
{
 int oldIndex = collection.IndexOf(item);
 int newIndex sCollection.IndexOf(item);
  if (oldIndex!=newIndex))
  {
    collection.Move(oldindex,newIndex);
  }
```

List is updated, but it lags too much. it has around 150 elements, not more.
So, what is the best way to sort and update binded collection when new item added?

Comment: I think you can binding the listview again after collection changed.

Comment: This will re-create the collection of view elements, it will lag.

Answer (score 0):

it lags, becouse if u want to short 150 items, then update it.
i think you can solve this if u use less of the memory or a "featherlight" code, i mean you can use a little bit harder but a better algorithm to solve the problem, or you can use many different ways like adding `Thread.Sleep(10);`, but is your computer a small one?
if it is, try it on an another system, good luck!

Regards